# Work emails going to recipients SPAM folder instead of inbox

Tags: email, spam-prevention

I am having an issue with emails coming from my employers email domain (@poweron.com) ending up in recipients SPAM folder instead of their inbox, here are the details.

On monday, the sales manager came to me and told me that several customers were reporting that email blasts that would usually be delivered to the inbox were showing up in spam.

I went online and found a tool (https://app.glockapps.com/) that allows you to test email delivery from one domain to a large selection of the most populat email providers (google, hotmail, outlook, yahoo, etc) and then show the results regarding if the email was delivered to the inbox or if it went to spam.   Here are the results of one of my tests

[image]

I also have checked senderscore.com, which is a tool that scores your mail servers IP address.    According to them my IP is 99/100.

[image]

Here is what my MX record looks like in DNS according to MXToolbox

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3amail.poweron.com&run=toolpage

```
Pref    Hostname    IP Address  TTL 
10  cloud1.spamtitan.com    198.20.73.147
SingleHop (AS32475) 120 min Blacklist Check      SMTP Test
10  cloud2.spamtitan.com    198.20.73.147
SingleHop (AS32475) 120 min Blacklist Check      SMTP Test
20  mx-caprica.zoneedit.com 64.68.198.23
easyDNS Technologies, Inc. (AS16686)    120 min Blacklist Check      SMTP Test
Test    Result
    DMARC Record Published  DMARC Record found
    DNS Record Published    DNS Record found
```

I have rDNS/PTR records configured for my domain, the only thing I have not configured yet is DKIM (mainly because I am having issues with the syntax of the TXT record, cant seem to get it to verify) - but even if I got that working I am not totally sure it would resolve our issue.

I do not have to deal with issues like this very often, so I am sort of stuck as to why this is happening.   Let me know if you need any further technical details..  Thanks!

Comment: You need to find out which RBLs have you listed, and the processes they require to clear the marks.

Comment: It’s nearly impossible to determine why your mail is going to someone else’s junk mail without getting the message from them. There are headers on the email to indicate why.

Comment: Yeah that’s sort of what I thought @Appleoddity but my attempts to get back the raw source email that is getting stuck in spam have not been successful.  I’ve asked several people that have reported the issue to have the recipient send back the spam email in a raw format but no one has responded back.

Comment: Are you able to send mail to your own external yahoo or gmail acct?

Comment: @Appleoddity yes, I am able to send email to test yahoo and gmail accounts from our domain.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information the only service blocking your domain is Microsoft. This will encompass a large number of people using Office 365, hotmail and Outlook.com email addresses.

Office 365 customers can create tickets with Microsoft and they are very responsive at fixing these problems on their end. I am not aware of a way for a non-paying consumer to get Microsoft to address this issue.

The best recommendation I can make is to work with the admin of an Office 365 tenant to submit a ticket with Microsoft. For some reason they have decided to blacklist your server or domain.

Here is more information you can provide to customers who may be concerned about your email going to spam: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/prevent-email-from-being-marked-as-spam-0

I am loathe to say this overly used statement, but the problem is on their end, not yours. Although there was probably some behavior from your end that initiated the blacklist. Such as a high number of complaints about mail you were sending.